# How to add an Image Cell to multiple items within a list view in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hello I am working on a app that is in a list view when you tap a item in the list view it takes you to another page I want to be able to add a image to the left side of the text within the label. however there are multiple labels in the lisview so how would I get a different image for each label I have the images in the content folder within my project

here's my xaml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App.HomePage">
  <ListView x:Name="listView" HasUnevenRows="true"  ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <Frame Padding="0,0,0,8" BackgroundColor="#d2d5d7">
            <Frame.Content>
              <Frame Padding="15,15,15,15"   OutlineColor="Gray" BackgroundColor="White">
                <Frame.Content>
                  <StackLayout Padding="20,0,0,0"  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                           TextColor="#69add1"
                           FontFamily="OpenSans-Light"
                           FontSize="24"/>
                  </StackLayout>
                </Frame.Content>
              </Frame>
            </Frame.Content>
          </Frame>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

here's my code behind:

```
using App.Data;
using App.Road;
using App.Plan;
using App.Radar;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App
{
    public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
    {
        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var name = new List<Tools>
                {
                     new Tools("Plan and Prepare"), 
                     new Tools("Contact Local Agency"),
                     new Tools("Road Closings"),
                     new Tools("Weather Radar")
            };

            listView.ItemsSource = name;
            Content = listView;
        }

        void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var tools = e.SelectedItem as Tools;

            if (tools == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            ContentPage page = null;

            switch (tools.Name)
            {
                case "Plan and Prepare":
                    page = new PlanHome();
                    break;
                case "Contact Local Agency":
                    page = new CountySelect();
                    break;

                case "Road Closings":
                    page = new RoadHome();
                    break;

                case "Weather Radar":
                    page = new RadarHome();
                    break;

                default:
                    page = new HomePage();
                    break;
            }

            ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
            page.BindingContext = tools;
            Navigation.PushAsync(page);
        }
    }
}
```

any help would be amazing!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a a [ImageCell](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance/#ImageCell) instead of a `ViewCell`.

Documentation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ImageCell/) and full example [here](https://www.syntaxismyui.com/xamarin-forms-listview-imagecell-recipe/).

Code sample:

```
<ListView x:Name="list">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ImageCell 
                            Text="{Binding Name}" 
                            Detail="{Binding Position, StringFormat='{0}'}" 
                            ImageSource="{Binding Image}">
                        </ImageCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and the example link what I ended up doing is keeping the ViewCell and just added <Image
                          HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                          Source="{Binding Image}" /> above the label and that did the trick :)

Comment: @jzeferino How to use ImageSource? I got a byte[] and should I call it "Image" in my list?

Comment: try this: `ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes));`

Answer (score 1):

I found one sample code solution.
Use ImageCell instead of ViewCell.

Code Sample:

```
 <ListView x:Name="listEntries" ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ImageCell
                Text="{Binding Name}"
                ImageSource="{Binding Image}"
                >
              </ImageCell>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

I changed the 'Image'-Property from String to ImageSource and then filled it with '`ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(pictureByteArray))`'

And it worked!